# How to Merge Multiple Website Account - Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

When my clients adds me as an admin on there Google Analytics account for the website I am going to manage. Each time a separate Account shows up on my Google analytics with a single property in it (that is the clients site).

Is it possible to merge all those accounts and keep them as properties under a Account I create, call it "Clients"

I currently have 20+ clients accounts and its getting overwhelming. Its would be great if I can move them to a single account and add each site as property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics does not have functionality for moving or organizing accounts.   This has been [requested in the Google product forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/GGZyFZmuJ5A/Gxo2FHUPCYIJ). The best that you can do is to rename your accounts.  Maybe you could name them all with a prefix such that they sort after your own sites and your sites come first.

From that same thread, user Whims posted instructions for renaming accounts:

> - Click on the Admin button in the orange bar at the upper right
> - Once on the Account Admin page.. select an account from the list in the provided table by clicking on it
> - On the next page select the Account Settings tab. there you can change the container account name